# Can't set WordPress permalinks with categories and subcategories

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

There is no answer to my question at wordpress.stackexchange.com so I've decided to try here.

At the WordPress-based website I'm working on I use categories and subcategories so the links to posts are like `category-level-1/category-level-2/post-name` and `category-level-1/category-level-2/category-level-3/post-name`

All posts are assigned only to the last level categories.

If I set custom permalink structure as `/%category%/%postname%` and then go at the frontend to the first level category page, I receive what I expect. But when I go to the second level category page (regardless of it has the third level category or no), a redirect is performed and I receive the page of single post from the third level category.

If I set custom permalink structure as `/%category%/%category%/%category%/%postname%` (three is max count of categories levels at my website) and then go to category page of any level, I receive what I expect. But names of categories are duplicated in the post links three times.

If I delete duplicates by adding to function.php the code like:

```
function custom_post_link($link, $post) {
    $link_parts = explode('/', $link);
    $link_parts = array_unique($link_parts);
    $link = implode('/', $link_parts);
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_post_link', 10, 2);
```

the links to posts become normal, but work only for the posts which are assigned to the third level category. For other posts I receive 404 error.

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you set on each category it's 'Parent Category'? I just checked and with permalink set to `/%category%/%postname%/` it works as expected.

Comment: Each category level 3 is assigned to its parent category level 2 and level 2 is assigned to its parent level 1